# Timeout change in ElasticSearch not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, timeout

My task is to change the ***Timeout*** time from ***1 min 15 s*** to ***3 min***
When I run the script:`sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service` it shows Timeout. So my next steps are:

**(1)** `$ sudo systemctl show elasticsearch | grep ^Timeout` which returns: `TimeoutStartUSec=1min 15s TimeoutStopUSec=infinity`

**(2)** Create a service drop-in configuration directory. `$ sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d`

**(3)** With this query now I`m trying to change the Timeout time: `$ echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=180" | sudo tee`

**(4)** Reload the system: `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

**(5)** And when I check the new Timeout it returns the same `TimeoutStartUSec=1min 15s TimeoutStopUSec=infinity`

Here is the full picture:
[image]

Why the system still returns the same Timeout time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing an answer for my question.
To change the TimeOut time all I did was:
`sudo su` and then did all the steps (from **1** to **5** from my question).

Answer (score 0):

You want to provide `tee` an output file. Try running `man tee`, it'll be of more detail.

Maybe do `.... | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/someconfigfile` instead

Comment: I did the following: `$ echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=180" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/someconfigfile` , then `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and still its shows me the old TimeOut time.